# How to reduce the size of the arrow in infowindow google map

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to customize google maps. I want to reduce the height and width of the arrow in infowindow google map. And if the arrow in left corner in bottom it looks good.

I don't know how to customize the arrow height and width and move that arrow to left corner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you need to create your own custom popup info window instead of using the standard info window

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Link](http://rohittank.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-infowindow-infobox-to-google.html) also this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max) for variable height and Width. If i am wrong then post your Question in Detail and if possible attach Images so user can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the arrow of default infoWindow of Google Maps, but id you're interested in 3rd party plugins then this is the right choice.

### [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/)

Here is the list of items that can be customized in infoBubble

[image]